# Multi-way redirection of System.out

Tags: java, stream

With approach shown in the following example, the output stream is being lost when an other class intercepts it. How to fix my program?

Console.java:

```
package interception;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import java.io.*;

public class Console extends JFrame 
{

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextPane textPane;

    private class Interceptor extends PrintStream
    {
        public Interceptor(OutputStream out)
        {
            super(out,true);
        }

        @Override
        public void print(String s)
        {
            super.print(s);
            textPane.setText(textPane.getText()+s);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() 
            {
                try 
                {
                    Console frame = new Console();
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                    System.out.print("System standard output stream test\n");
                    new Troll();
                    System.out.print("Haters gonna hate\n");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Console() 
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setEditable(false);
        contentPane.add(textPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        redirectStream();
    }

    protected void redirectStream()
    {
        PrintStream iout = new Interceptor(System.out);
        System.setOut(iout);        
    }
}
```

Troll.java:

```
package interception;

import java.io.*;

public class Troll 
{
    private class Interceptor extends PrintStream
    {
        public Interceptor(OutputStream out)
        {
            super(out,true);
        }

        @Override
        public void print(String s)
        {
            super.print(s);
        }
    }

    public Troll()
    {
        PrintStream iout = new Interceptor(System.out); 
        System.setOut(iout);

        System.out.print("I've stolen your stream bwahaha!\n");
    }
}
```

[image]

In other words - after construction of "Troll" the Console is no longer able to intercept the output stream, so the text "haters gonna hate" isn't shown inside it. This is the problem.

**UPDATE**

Closing stream for `Troll` class is obviously unacceptable solution.

Comment: I don't think you can do anything about this, as there's no way provided to chain the streams

Answer (score 0):

Were you thinking that the Troll.Interceptor.print() would automatically call the print() method in Console.Interceptor?  That doesn't happen.  When Troll.Interceptor.print() calls super.print(s), it calls the print() method defined for PrintStream.  You've constructed the PrintStream with an *OutputStream*, and OutputStream doesn't have a print() method.  The PrintStream logic will perhaps call write() on the underlying OutputStream (and write() has not been overridden), but there's no way for it to call print(), since PrintStream.print() doesn't see "out" as another PrintStream.

I don't know how much this helps you, since I'm not really clear on what you were expecting it to do.

Comment: You didn't understand me. Please read the postscript of my question.

Comment: So the problem is that you want the output to behave the same way after run() calls new Troll() as it did before?  If that's the case, I think just `PrintStream saveOut = System.out;` before new Troll(), and `System.setOut(saveOut);` afterwards, will work.  If that still isn't what you need, please explain further.  Thanks.

Comment: If I had done what you said, the same problem would have still remained, but on the `Troll` class side.

Comment: I think the problem is that you've got two classes fighting over a global resource, i.e. System.out.  There's no reason to use the global.  If you want output generated by the Console class to take one path, and output generated by the Troll class to take another path, then don't use System.out.  In both classes, make iout a private class member, don't use System.setOut, and use `iout.print(...)` instead of `System.out.print(...)`.  On the other hand, if you want this interception to affect System.out.print() calls made by _other_ classes, then you've got some design work to do.

Comment: Re my last comment, inside run() that will need to be `frame.iout.print(...)`